# Оформление при цитировании слов, фраз или предложений

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата, цитирование

В последнее время у меня возникла некоторая путаница с оформлением слов, фраз и предложений в качестве цитат.

1. *Твоя фраза «я вас не ждал» может обидеть собеседника.*

Саму фразу нужно писать со строчной буквы или с прописной?

2. *Слово «мама» — первое слово, которое выговаривает младенец.*

На этом портале я часто вижу, что в таком случае кавычки часто не ставятся.

*С отглагольным предлогом **несмотря на** часто возникают трудности.*

Как же правильно?

3. *Предложение(:) "Она не сводила глаз с дороги, что ведёт через рощу" (—) является сложноподченённым.*

Нужно ли здесь оформление, как цитаты, или предложение является определением к слову *предложение*?

В своём молодёжном блоге я часто применяю цитаты в качестве членов предложения как средство для выражения иронии. Верно ли они оформлены такие цитаты?

4. *Мой личный совет: если ты как специалист хочешь всегда быть в цене, не попадай в ментальную ловушку «Буду заниматься тем, чем интересно».*
5. *Ты хочешь наконец-то заняться собой, но "ой, у меня тут срочные дела, и вообще — сейчас на работе такой завал, такой завал".*
6. *Всем уже надоели банальные советы, что нужно просто «развиваться, преодолевать барьеры и идти к своим целям», пустая мотивация в стиле «начни что-то менять!», «выходи из зоны комфорта!», «иди к своему успеху!».*
7. *Если шеф предлагает тебе взять на себя новые функции, пользуйся возможностью. Не надо вот этих "а это не входит в мои обязанности!".*

Answer (score 3):

1) У Розенталя на эту ему дается следующий текст.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

**Примечание.** Подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, **выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится:**
Это «не хочу» поразило Антона Прокофьевича (Г.); Предположение дневального, что «взводный нажрался и дрыхнет где-то в избе», всё больше собирало сторонников (Ф.); Он вспомнил **пословицу** «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана; С криком «Спасайте детей!» юноша бросился в горящее здание.

Но если перед подлинным выражением имеются слова **предложение, выражение, надпись и т. п., то перед ними ставится двоеточие**: Над воротами возвысилась вывеска с **подписью:** «Здесь продаются и обиваются гробы простые и крашеные…» (П.); Разберите **предложение**: «Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».

2) Из этого следует, что разрешается: 1) ставить двоеточие или не ставить; 2) выбирать прописную букву или строчную. А из ответов Грамоты.ру  следует, что можно применять курсив или кавычки. http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2&start=15

3) Как сделать выбор? Думаю, что выбор **прописной или строчной буквы** зависит от объема цитаты и ее законченности. **При постановке двоеточия** следует дополнительно учитывать структуру основного предложения и возможность сделать предупредительную паузу.  **Выбор курсива или кавычек очень индивидуален**, четких правил здесь нет.

4) Например:

Предложение **«Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром»** является сложносочиненным.

Предложение ***Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром*** является сложносочиненным.

Разберите предложение: ***«Сверкнула молния, и грянул гром».***

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (примеры решения)**

1) Твоя фраза **«Я вас не ждал»** может обидеть собеседника. Фраза **«я вас не ждал»** может обидеть собеседника.

2) Слово **«мама»** — это первое, что выговаривает младенец. Слово ***мама*** — это первое, что выговаривает младенец.

3) С отглагольным предлогом **"несмотря на"** часто возникают трудности. С отглагольным предлогом ***несмотря на*** часто возникают трудности.

4) Предложение  **"Она не сводила глаз с дороги, что ведёт через рощу"** является сложноподченённым.

4) Мой личный совет: если ты как специалист хочешь всегда быть в цене, не попадай в ментальную ловушку **«буду заниматься тем, что интересно»**.

5) Ты хочешь наконец-то заняться собой, но **"ой, у меня тут срочные дела, и вообще — сейчас на работе такой завал, такой завал"**.

6) Всем уже надоели  банальные советы, что **"нужно  развиваться, преодолевать барьеры и идти к своим целям"**, а также    пустая мотивация в стиле **«начни что-то менять!», «выходи из зоны комфорта!», «иди к своему успеху!».**

7) Если шеф предлагает тебе взять на себя новые функции, то пользуйся возможностью. И уж в любом случае не надо делать заявлений на тему **"а это не входит в мои обязанности!".**

Comment: Jasmin, Было вы замечательно, если бы Вы отредактировали все семь предложений из вопроса.

Comment: А если перед цитатой ставить двоеточие, но цитатой предложение не заканчивается, нужно после цитаты ставить тире или запятую и тире (если в конце цитаты отсутсвует знак) как в случае с прямой речью? А почему вы решили «буду заниматься, чем интересно» написать со строчной буквы? Это разве не имя собственное, название ловушки? Или возможно возможно двоякое написание?

Comment: 1) Приводите конкретные примеры, а не описания структуры (в них трудно разобраться). 2) Не может предложение быть именем собственным и названием для ментальной ловушки. Это просто описания содержания  этой ловушки.